# Define Name with Global Scope but Local Reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel project with multiple datasheets. I want to define a name for a cell that can be used in all sheets within the project, but keep the referenced cell local.

For example, say in datasheet `Burton` I have a cell `O16` that I want to name `Total_Production`. I would first define a name with the following properties: [image]

Now in datasheet `Middlefield` I want to use that same defined name `Total_Production` but have it reference the **Middlefield** `O16` cell. However, when I use that name, the cell being referenced is from the `Burton` datasheet.

How can I define a name that has global scope but refers to a local cell?

I have already tried modifying the `Refers to:` field to `=$O$16` or `=Workbook!$O$16` but neither seem to function how I would have expected.

I plan to use this with many many more datasheets, but I gave 2 sheets for explanatory purposes.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't use the same name for two different ranges in the same workbook -- you could number the ranges (ex: Middlefield_1, Middlefield_2, etc.), or add the sheet name (ex: Middlefield_Sheet1, Middlefield_Sheet2, etc.)